# Как авторизовать аккаунт instagram на Java

Tags: java, api, jsoup, instagram

я только учусь и хотелось бы узнать, как я могу реализовать следующую идею:
Нам надо авторизовать свою учётную запись и некий someString будет принимать ссылку на историю в instagram. Нам нужно,чтобы просмотр этой истории осуществлялся через наш аккаунт и отображался в списке тех, кто просмотрел историю.
Jsoup пробовал немного разобрать, но там как-то всё больно мудрено (или я чего не понял). В любом случае, прошу дать хотя бы наводку, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Можете попробовать [данную](https://github.com/instagram4j/instagram4j) библиотеку, эмулирующую андроид устройство.

Comment: ничего не понятно. Зачем вам в данном случае JSoup?

Comment: @ArturVartanyan я думал, что можно как-то использовать его для post запросов

Comment: тогда лучше библиотеку под запрос использовать, по моему мнению. Какой-нибудь `ApacheHttpRequest` или `RestTemplate` от `Spring-Web`